# How to learn programming for Web Development using microsoft technologies

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

i am programmer but not good i am working with c# , [asp.net](http://asp.net) and MVC too. so how i can improve our coding skill for develop a better web apps. means how can i learn it.

Comment: Although not overly critical, where are you coming from? Java, PHP, Python, Ruby?... any particular frameworks that you are used to (e.g. so that we can compare against/guide you)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you need some good ASP.NET MVC resources as the other answers have pointed out. It is also worth investing time in learning about the .NET framework itself. For this purpose I thoroughly recommend [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621632) by [Jeffrey Richter](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jeffreyr/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend getting [Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=asp.net+mvc+book&oe=UTF-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=8353083839880475321&ei=ScP2SpOeIsGV8Abx2r3zCQ&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CAoQ8wIwAQ#ps-sellers) and working through it and the examples in it, particularly the [Nerd Dinner](http://www.nerddinner.com) Example.

Answer (score 0):

Learning resources:

1. [The Official ASP.Net site](http://www.asp.net/learn/) (Video, Tutorials, Documentation)
2. [Learn ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/)

Comment: why are you give this link all asp.net programmer know this site

Comment: That's why. I want to make sure he, as asp.net programmer, know this site

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should start with is some beginning book and move towards professional. One book could be

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-ASP-NET-3-5-2008-Professional/dp/1590598911](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598911)

once u understand this book then u can for MVC book like.

www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Framework-Steven-Sanderson/dp/1430210079

In between try to learn by googling topics like. TDD(Test Driven Development), DI(Dependency Injection) and Other design Patterns